# PayPal SDK iOS - Login always return INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR (500)

Tags: ios, paypal

After successfully integrating iOS PayPal SDK and testing with no-network mode, I created some test users in the app dashboard and switched to sandbox mode. When I try to login I always get this INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR as below:

> PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR -
>   System error. Please try again later. (500) | PayPal Debug-ID:
>   003f3b97339c5 [sandbox, PayPal iOS SDK 2.8.1]

I gave it some time, even a day as the description tell me to try again later but the failure persists. Is there any additional step I should be doing? Or maybe this is not related to my end?

Comment: why are you doing in no-network mode testing

Comment: This is weird, have you added ClientIDEnviroments on AppDelegate for SandBox mode?

Comment: problem is because your account is non-U.S. based ? may be

Comment: I was getting this and it turns out that our (The company I work for) internal firewall was blocking the address I was POSTing to and I was just getting that error back. Once we added it to the firewalls exceptions list it start working perfectly. So I'd recommend checking your firewall settings.

Comment: The account is indeed non-US but it is supported as it is stated on the docs. Yes the ClientID is correct and I double checked it just in case.

@Popeye I checked with the network guys and it seems to no firewall. But I can't confirm myself on this one, maybe this is the problem.

Comment: @CJ_COIMBRA i have used Paypal sdk its working fine  you me, for you demo apps of paypal working?

Comment: @CJ_COIMBRA What the network guys tell you and what is the truth is sometimes two completely different things. My network guys told me the same thing until I told them to add the paypal URLs to the exceptions list and it started working.

Comment: I get the same error using the SampleApp.

Comment: The 500 means the PayPal code encountered an error that they havn't even mapped to a real return code. Since the SDK works for other people there is probably some error in how you are using it but people here won't be able to identify it remotely (besides shots in the dark/things that have failed for them) without your code. Or you can ask PayPal support for help, giving them that PayPal DebugID. It's an internal error, thus a bug on their side (albeit probably a bug you only hit because you also have made an error).

Comment: I got it to work by changing the sandbox test user Country to US and also allowing users that not confirmed the e-mail to use the App.

Answer (score 0):

A 500 response indicates a bug in the PayPal backend. In general, debug IDs should be sent to [https://www.paypal.com/mts](merchant support). They can examine the logs for more information and file a problem report with the appropriate internal team.

However, I will bring this case to their attention.

Answer (score 0):

This particular error has to do with your buyer account not being completely set up according to the country it's registered with. Your buyer account needs a Tax ID set up on it in order to be able to process. As for the 500 Error, this was corrected shortly after you posted the question so that a more appropriate error is returned.